# How to copy a value of an array loaded into a listbox to a separate textboox.

Tags: c#

I am trying to do a project for a C# class. I have a program that loads data from a file into arrays then copies the arrays into list boxes. I want then to select the in the listbox with my mouse and then copy it into a listbox. I have tried this code:

> lblemployeeNameTwo.Text = listIstName.SelectedIndex.ToString();

But that copies the index number of the array into the textbox and not the actual value so instead of Smith, it copies index 4 which represents smith.

Thank you for helping me in advance!

Comment: *This question does not show any research effort.*  Sorry, I am out of votes for today.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Ok thank you ill try to do better research and take the tour thanks!

Comment: Try `lblemployeeNameTwo.Items.Add(listIstName.SelectedIndex.ToString());`

Comment: C# doesn't have listboxes or textboxes; are you using WPF? WinForms? UWP? ASP.NET? It would help if you showed us your code that “loads data from a file into arrays then copies the arrays into list boxes”.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this to get the selected index:

```
lblemployeeNameTwo.Text = listIstName.SelectedIndex.ToString();
```

You can do this for the string of the selected item:

```
lblemployeeNameTwo.Text = listIstName.SelectedItem.ToString();
```